# Short story about group is paid to misremember false things until they become part of history

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story a couple of years ago and I cannot remember / find it at all.

**Some background:** It is a very short story (a couple of pages). On a 'dailysciencefiction.com' where you can browse / flip over thousands of 1 paragraph to ~10 page stories. It is probably by an amateur (the site has tons of unpublished stories)

**The story:** The story is set in a cafe. The narrator is part of an organization that purposefully misremembers or misspeaks about events until they become true. The narrator is meeting with a prospective client and explaining what his organization does. For example, if you had an affair, this organization has their thousands of everyday operatives constantly saying you did not until that's what people actually remember.

The narrator is rather cynical and, in the end, it is revealed he is part of this organization because he is trying to will his wife back to life by having enough people remember / say she is alive.

Comment: Was it specifically on **dailysciencefiction.com**?

Comment: Yes, specifically on dailysciencefiction.com

Comment: Wow. That twist ending is incredibly surprising and sad.

Answer (score 7):

This is [The Rememberists](https://dailysciencefiction.com/hither-and-yon/alternate-history/thomas-a-mays/the-rememberists) by Thomas A Mays

Quote about the organization

> He looked at his guest in the diner's booth and stirred his cup. "My
> gift is one of preternatural credulity. You tell me how things
> happened, and I'll believe you. I'll share your story with my equally
> unquestioning brethren around the globe, and together we remember your
> version of history. Soon, a tipping point is reached where belief
> becomes reality and the deed is done, your past is changed."

Quote regarding the wife:

> Ansel sighed, apologetic. "I need you to remember something for me.
> Remember it and believe it."
>
> She appeared cautious. "Okay. What is it?"
>
> "Just this: There, at the last, Anna believed me, believed that I
> loved her. And that was enough. She didn't pull the trigger. She
> simply lived. Will you remember that for me? Please?"

Answer (score 4):

Sounds awfully like the French novel "Les falsificateurs" by Antoine Bello.

It's been translated into English under the name "The Falsifiers". The book centers around a secret international organization, the CFR, which falsifies reality and rewrites history.

The "secret organization" is falsifying historical and/or current events, from the smallest to the biggest, although we don't know why. They are using all types of methods from falsifying documentary sources to faking testimonies or confusing journalists. For instance it's mentioned in the book that the 1st dog in space Laika was a lie created from scratch by the organization to lead to a weapon race between the USA and Russia. Really entertaining book that plays with the conspiracy theory concept!

However, it's not the answer you're seeking since it's not a short story and there's no dead wife in the storyline. But you may enjoy it (I certainly did!)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please could you [edit] your answer to include some more detail about this story and why it matches the description given in the question? Thanks :-)

Comment: The "secret organization" is falsifying historical and/or current events, from the smallest to the biggest, although we don't know why. They are using all types of methods from falsifying documentary sources to faking testimonies or confusing journalists. For instance it's mentioned in the book that the 1st dog in space Laika was a lie created from scratch by the organization to lead to a weapon race between the USA and Russia. Really entertaining book that plays with the conspiracy theory concept!